# Working remotely part-time in Malaysia with student visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, students, malaysia

I'm staying in Malaysia with a student Visa and I'm wondering if it is required to have work visa if you are working remotely and getting paid from a company based in a country other than Malaysia.

Also I wonder making money from selling another country stocks online or getting paid from something like [bounrysource](https://www.bountysource.com) need work visa or not.

Being unable to read Malay language or know the sources the I couldn't find any definition of employment or working in Malaysian Law.

I do know that income from other countries is [tax free in Malaysia](https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/1203859?author=cheahcw2003).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not being an expert with this subject at all, I would still say (being an expat living in Malaysia myself) that as you are not a permanent resident in Malysia nor seem to hold a  [Certificate of Residence](http://www.hasil.org.my/goindex.php?kump=5&skum=6&posi=6&unit=1&sequ=1) and no working visa, you would be subject to tax in your country of origin and not in Malaysia. This would also mean that if you make money through online sources and pay taxes in the country from which you originate it would not require you to register this income in Malaysia, hence eliminating the need for a work visa.

However if you intend to find employment in Malaysia your employer would need to furnish you with an "Employment Pass" or similar work visa arrangement.